# Equivalent criteria or HQL?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have below SQL query. what is the equivalent Criteria or HQL query?

```
select max(id) from 
(
select max(id) id from TableA
union 
select max(id) from TableB
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent, because there is no UNION in HQL or Criteria. Some workarounds are:

- use native query
- build view and map it for read only purposes (if it for some reason really not possible to use native query)
- perform two queries and choose in Java code which value to use.